# Wildcards in database

Tags: sql, regex

Any one have any pointers how I can store wildcards in a database and the see which row(s) a string matches? Can it be done?

e.g.
DB contains a table like:

[image: two column table with wildcards in col one]

So john3136 should get 10 times his regular pay. fred3136 would get half his regular pay.
harry3136 probably crashes the app since there is no matching data ;-)

The code needs to do something like:

```
foreach(Employee e in all_employees) {
    SELECT Multiplier FROM PayScales WHERE
        //??? e.Name matches the PayScales.Name wildcard
}
```

Thanks!

**Edit**
This is a real world issue: I've got a parameter file that contains wildcards. The code currently iterates through employees, iterates through the param file looking for a match - you can see why I'd like to "databaserize" it ;-)

Wildcards are optional. The row could have said "john3136" to only match one employee.  (The real app isn't actually employees, so it does make sense even if it looks like overkill in this simple example)

One option open: I do know all the employee names before I start, so I could iterate through them and effectively expand the wildcards in a temporary table. (so if I have john3136* in the starting table, it might expand to john3136, john31366 etc based on the list of employees). I was hoping to find a better way than this since it requires more maintenance (e.g. if we add functionality to add an employee we need to maintain the expanded wildcards table).

Comment: sounds fragile at best...

Comment: You probably don't want to store wildcards, but you can always just use `LIKE`

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: it's mapping existing behavior into DB world - we've got a parameter file with expressions as written + code to go through it an find which line of the file matches. I was hoping there was a way to flip this so I can load the file into an in memory DB and just query to find matches. At the moment this is just theoretical, but if it can be done, probably looking at HSQLDB in a Java app.

Comment: @John3136 if you plan to use `LIKE` I am happy to post a `REGEX` ;)

Comment: @bonCodigo: I'm happy to use whatever works! - if you think you have the answer, give it a go! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM payscales 
 WHERE e.Name 
  LIKE regexp_replace(name, E'^\\*|\\*$', '%', 'g');
```

I don't know which database you're using. The above query works on `postgresql` and just replace your trailing and leading wildcard with `%`, that's the `LIKE` wildcard.

If no wildcard is present, it must match the full string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but not sure if it works for me. The Name column doesn't have to have wildcards - but it can, so wildcarding the query doesn't work because it's not something that should be supplied globally.

Comment: that code appears to answer your question for postgresql database, using `replace(name,'*','%')` instead of `regexp_replace(...)` would give portablility to more database platforms (so long as no names contain `'%'`)