# Is there a database that can store regex as values?

Tags: regex, database

I am looking for a database that can store regex expressions as values. E.g. somthing like this:

```
{:name => "Tim", :count => 3, :expression => /t+/},
{:name => "Rob", :count => 4, :expression => /a\d+/},
{:name => "Fil", :count => 1, :expression => /tt/},
{:name => "Marc", :count => 1, :expression => /bb/}
```

So I could return rows/documents based on whether the query matches the expression or not (e.g."FIND rows WHERE "tt" =~ :expression"). And get Tim and Fil rows as the result. Most databases can do the exactly opposite thing (check whether a text field matches a regex query). But neither mongo nor postgres can do the opposite thing, unfortunately.

P.S. Or perhaps I am wrong and there are some extensions for postgres or mongo that allow me to store regex?

Comment: I don't know of anything like this (mostly because it wouldn't be indexable, at a minimum), but Elasticsearch provides "percolators" and RethinkDB provides push responses to queries, which might help depending on your use case. What are you wanting to achieve?

Comment: You don't want to do that in real life, because the DBMS would have to process most of the rows in the table ... DBMS in practice uses indexes, and these work well on textual values, not something more complex. In other words, better do the regexp matching in the client, or inside some stored procedure in the server.

Comment: I asked a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250901/wildcards-in-database but I didn't get any useful answers.

Comment: The issue isn't much about how the regex is stored. DBs most likely will store regex as strings. The issue is with the search expression where a column is not treated a as a regex. There probably is an operator similar to `=~` that will allow the search to be regex even when the column is a string. In Oracle DB, regex is done via plsql. I'm guessing this will work the way you wanted.

Comment: "Tim" is a valid regular expression that matches the string "Tim". What do you actually want to do here?

Comment: Check this doc from mongodb http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/. It might become handy for you.

Comment: i think you can use any database if you can encode and decode  the regex properly

Comment: 2 Basile, yes I am already aware of the index problem... don't know yet how to work around it. Processing everything in client would basically mean eliminating the DB and just storing everything in ruby hashes. Not entirely acceptable, and again, still no indexes...
2 Elyasin. Yep, it was very useful. I just got sick recently and couldn't check the answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oracle database can do that.

Example query: `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(first_name, '^Ste(v|ph)en$')`

You want to select an regexp from a column, See SQL Fiddle example below for an example.

---

## [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Choose Oracle database.

In schema window execute the following:

```
CREATE TABLE regexp (name VARCHAR2(20), count NUMBER, regexp VARCHAR2(50));

INSERT INTO regexp VALUES ('Tim', 3, 't+');
INSERT INTO regexp VALUES ('Rob', 4, 'a\d+');
INSERT INTO regexp VALUES ('Fil', 1, 'tt');
INSERT INTO regexp VALUES ('Marc', 1, 'bb');
COMMIT;
```

Execute an SQL statement, e.g. (as you mentioned in your question):

```
SELECT * FROM regexp WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('tt', regexp);
```

Yields:

```
NAME    COUNT   REGEXP
Tim     3       t+
Fil     1       tt
```

---

Reference [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_regexp.htm#g1015343).

***Excerpt:***

> Oracle Database implements regular expression support with a set of
>   Oracle Database SQL functions and conditions that enable you to search
>   and manipulate string data. You can use these functions in any
>   environment that supports Oracle Database SQL. You can use these
>   functions on a text literal, bind variable, or any column that holds
>   character data such as CHAR, NCHAR, CLOB, NCLOB, NVARCHAR2, and
>   VARCHAR2 (but not LONG).

***And some more info to consider:***

> A string literal in a REGEXP function or condition conforms to the
>   rules of SQL text literals. By default, regular expressions must be
>   enclosed in single quotes. If your regular expression includes the
>   single quote character, then enter two single quotation marks to
>   represent one single quotation mark within the expression. This
>   technique ensures that the entire expression is interpreted by the SQL
>   function and improves the readability of your code. You can also use
>   the q-quote syntax to define your own character to terminate a text
>   literal. For example, you could delimit your regular expression with
>   the pound sign (#) and then use a single quote within the expression.
>
> **Note**: If your expression comes from a column or a bind variable, then
>   the same rules for quoting do not apply.

Note there is no column type named RegEx, you would need to save the string as is, in a textual column.

Also you can use RegEx in constraint checking and when you project columns.

Comment: But the regexp is stored in the table, so you should adjust your example

Comment: I did not downvote, but you really should adjust your example.

Comment: The OP gave "e.g."FIND rows WHERE "tt" =~ :expression"". My example gives an idea to do it in Oracle. How would you like to adjust it? Feel free to edit if you want.

Comment: Are you saying that if I store regex in db, I can use the same expression to match it against a string query and it will work?
E.g. WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('Stephen', first_name) will match a row where first_name is equal to '^Ste(v|ph)en$'?

Comment: @AntonDinoMois Yes, I added an example.

Comment: Currently, I'm focusing my application on Cassandra and Regex. I'm looking to fetch stored Regex also - ideally in Regex or similar - which is to say, in memory.

Do you know of anything that I could use?

My question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358699/return-a-regex-pattern-from-a-search-in-database-nodejs](here)

Answer (score 9):

MongoDB will allow you to store actual regular expressions (i.e. not a string representing a regular expression), as shown below:

```
> db.mycoll.insertOne({myregex: /aa/})
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "insertedId" : ObjectId("5826414249bf0898c1059b38")
}
> db.mycoll.insertOne({myregex: /a+/})
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "insertedId" : ObjectId("5826414949bf0898c1059b39")
}
> db.mycoll.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5826414249bf0898c1059b38"), "myregex" : /aa/ }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5826414949bf0898c1059b39"), "myregex" : /a+/ }
```

You can use this to then query for rows with a regex that matches a query, as follows:

```
> db.mycoll.find(function() { return this.myregex.test('a'); } )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5826414949bf0898c1059b39"), "myregex" : /a+/ }
```

Here we search for rows where the string 'a' is matched by the `myregex` field, resulting in the second document, with regex `/a+/`, being returned.

Comment: BUT you must be careful if you want to use then outside the mongo shell: the mongodb JS native driver 3.0.10 does not appropriately convert the BSONRegExp to JS RegExp. (Neither the Timestamp object, BTW)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server (and probably some other SQL databases) supports this out of the box, though as has been noted before, this can only be executed by the database as a table scan -- something to keep in mind if you have large numbers of regexes. You just reverse the usual order of the LIKE operator:

```
create table demo.query
(
    id int identity not null,
    regex nvarchar(max),
    primary key(id)
);

insert into demo.query (regex) values ('aa%');

select * from demo.query where 'aaaa' like regex;
```

Looks a little funny, but it's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Ely's answer, thought of letting you all know that MySQL also supports this.
In http://sqlfiddle.com/, I tested with MySQL 5.6
Build schema:

```
CREATE TABLE rule (name VARCHAR(20), tot INT, exp VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO rule VALUES ('Tim', 3, 't+');
INSERT INTO rule VALUES ('Rob', 4, 'a\d+');
INSERT INTO rule VALUES ('Fil', 1, 'tt');
INSERT INTO rule VALUES ('Jack', 1, '^tt$');
INSERT INTO rule VALUES ('Marc', 1, 'bb');
COMMIT;
```

Test:

```
select * from rule where 'ttt' RLIKE exp ;
```

Expected: rows for Tim, and Fil