# Return a Regex Pattern from a search in database (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, regex, database, node.js

I'm currently using Redis, but examples in any database (that are good with NodeJS) would be good to get me going.

I'm looking to find Regex Patterns from a list, by providing potential matches.

I want to query my database of patterns and ask it - "which patterns would match this string?"

**Example**

Pattern Database:

```
(\/some\/)

(\/relative\/)

(\/other\/)
```

Search: "/some/relative/url/"

Return:

```
(\/some\/)

(\/relative\/)
```

Search: "/some/other/url/"

Return:

```
(\/some\/)

(\/other\/)
```

So my question is: is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible (to my knowledge) using only redis call. I suggest loading all the regular expressions from the database and running them in javascript to figure out which ones match.

Comment: I thought that myself, but I thought I'd ask to see if anyone can come up with something.

Comment: Excuse the original answer mentioning SQL. I knew you were talking about redis, which is why I answered as I did. There *are* ways to do this in SQL, but I guess thats not your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a way to that. You need to treat the pattern to be stored as a string, then retrieve them as you retrieve any other string  from the redis datastore. Just for your reference I am giving a link to redis-nodejs tutorial I found - [Using Redis With Nodejs](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-redis-node-js/).

Comment: Further you can also read the following  question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837762/is-there-a-database-that-can-store-regex-as-values