# Can we store Regular expressions as values in SqlLite Database in android?

Tags: android, regex, database, sqlite, escaping

I'm trying to store Regular Expressions-like values in Sqllite Database (most of them are special characters like regex) but i'm getting this error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "com": 
     syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: 
     insert into sample (indexId,tag) values (1,'dfvfdv/ ;''e;g=[;''''/.'';.')
```

I am trying to parse escape sequence using this:

```
public String escapeSequence(String s){
    return DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(s);
}
```

but it's not helping, is there something i'm doing wrong? or is there any way to do this properly?

even tried
`public String escapeSequence(String s){
        String a=s.replaceAll("'", "''");
        String b=DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(a);
        return b;
    }`

I'm trying to create a messenger kind of app, where i have to store Messages where message can be anything... (most of the time i don't have any control over that)

I've checked [Is there a database that can store regex as values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837762/is-there-a-database-that-can-store-regex-as-values) but doesn't really answer my question...

Comment: What is wrong with `DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(s)`?

Comment: so it's not working for strings like: //'/'
dgd
fggf
dfvfdv/ ;'e;g=[;''/.';.
ddffd
dsdsdsds
hgghgh
gbfnfgdgng
SDFSF

Comment: Don't insert strings you receive from somewhere else directly in SQL ever. Instead use `?` variables and bind the values.

Comment: @laalto sorry i did not get that could you please elaborate ?

Comment: Depends on your code. If you use `ContentValues` it gets transformed to variable binding under the hood. If you use e.g. `execSQL()` then have a look at the bindArguments param (where you supply the values for the `?` variables in your SQL).

Comment: @laalto Surprisingly that did the trick..... (if you post this answer i can accept) but i'd really like to know why using Contentvalues solved it? what's wrong with a Query approach using a StringBuilder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructing SQL strings from values obtained from untrusted sources (such as user input) opens your app for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) problems, and the kind of syntax issues you are seeing now.

Syntax issues and SQL injection can be avoided by using [`?` variables and binding the values](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).

On Android SQLite, you can use variable binding by using `ContentValues` with `SQLiteDatabase` methods that accept it such as `insert()` or `update()`. For selection or raw SQL, supply variables as `?` in the SQL expression and the values in the `selectionArgs` or `bindArgs` array param.

Answer (score 2):

The only char you have to escape is `'` into double `''`

that is, I'm using this wrapper:

`mystring.replaceAll("'", "''")`

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

> A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes ('). A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two single quotes in a row - as in Pascal. C-style escapes using the backslash character are not supported because they are not standard SQL.

I've tested your code here: http://sqliteonline.com/

this doesn't work:

```
CREATE TABLE regexp (name VARCHAR2(20), regexp VARCHAR2(50));

insert into regexp (name,regexp) values {'test','dfvfdv/ ;''e;g=[;''''/.'';.'}

select * from regexp
```

but this works:

```
CREATE TABLE regexp (name VARCHAR2(20), regexp VARCHAR2(50));

insert into regexp (name,regexp) values ('test','dfvfdv/ ;''e;g=[;''''/.'';.')

select * from regexp
```

Just replace this figured parenthesis `{}` to those `()`

Comment: but what about other characters ? do i have to match all characters manually ? and store it...(seems like a costly operation)

Comment: replacing chars is a costly operation where i'm trying to store like 100-150 records per minute....(with normal text i'm still able to store like that)

Comment: i tried your method, it still does not work for string values like  '('''''//''''/'''' dfvfdv/ ;''''e;g=[;''''''''/.'''';.ddfdfd' )'

Comment: @CodeMan , of course it doesn't work. This string is wrong. Write namely the string you want to put

Comment: @CodeMan , this string works: `'(''''''//''''/'''' dfvfdv/ ;''''e;g=[;''''''''/.'''';.ddfdfd'' )' `

Comment: end  braces are not included, however i don't have real control over  the data string (because it has no validation) because it has to  support any message..

Comment: Omg, just use replaceAll I've wrote in the body of my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126816/discussion-between-codeman-and-vyacheslav).